# Проблема с плагином Yoast SEO

Tags: html, wordpress, wp-plugin

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после активации плагина - сайт ниже шапки не хочет грузиться. Деактивирую - всё снова работает.
Файл header.php:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        <?php wp_title(''); ?>
    </title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

В итоге получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили, которые прописаны в function.php, не подключаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включайте ошибки в браузер или см в логах.

См [дополнительно](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD).

Можно также методом отключения плагинов и переключения на дефолтную тему найти кто виноват.

См [Инструкция по поиску виновного в пп 3-6](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B).